# Python regular expression for height?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that works for the different types of height inputs, it should work for the following examples below:

5-10

5-09

5-9

6'

6'0

5'9"

5'09"

5'9

5'09

I don't need to consider values below 4'0 or above 6'11.

Here's my regular expression so far:

```
[456][-']\d{1,2}"?
```

I need to make the `"` not work if there is a `-` between feet and inches.

Also, for the inches part, I am currently allowing for either 1 or 2 digits, when I really only want to allow for two digits when the first digit is a 0 or 1, and if it is 1, the second digit can only be 0 or 1.

For example, 00-09 should work but and 10 and 11 should work but not 12 or any other two-digit number.

Comment: Hello, I changed the question to clarify the examples. In my example specifically , I know that there should be a newline after the end of the string so I am not worried about "He was 5'9" on 6-10-2001" incorrectly returning 6-10

Comment: Much better. I still suggest you clarify, "I don't need to consider values below 4'0 or above 6'11"? Perhaps something like, *The text will not contain values below 4'0 or above 6'11"* (if that's what you mean). Also, you should include the point made in your comment above in the question itself. In general, questions should be self-contained and not rely on readers reading comments to fully understand them.

Answer (score 1):

You might use an alternation with an optional `-` and digits part, or match the `'` followed by a second `'` and use a capture group with an if clause to match up the `"`

```
\b(?<![-'"])(?:1[01]|0?\d)(?:'(?:(?:1[01]|0?\d)\b"?)?|-(?:1[01]|0?\d\b))(?![-'"])
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?<![-'"])` Negative lookbehind, assert not `'` or `-` or `"` directly to the left
- `(?:1[01]|0?\d)` Match from `0-9` with optional leading 0 and 10 and 11
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `'` Match literally
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?:1[01]|0?\d)\b`
    - `"?` Match optional `"`
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
  - `|` Or
  - `-` Match literally
  - `(?:1[01]|0?\d\b)` Match 0-9 10 or 11 followed by a word boundary
- `)` Close the outer group
- `(?![-'"])` Negative lookahead, assert not `-` or `'` or `"` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/veyxY5/1)